# Unable to connect to local Docker for Mac web server via IP address. Bonjour (mDNS) connection works fine

Tags: network, dns, bonjour, docker

I am currently running an application via Docker for Mac.

I have ensured that the application is properly forwarding the ports via a docker-compose file. I have forwarded port 8083 from the application container to the host machine. I can access the application via "localhost:8083" in the host machines browser.

Other computers on the network are experiencing a strange issue. I can access the application via other computers by using the host computers Bonjour (mDNS) address like so: "neptr.local:8083". However, I cannot connect to the application using the host machines IP address. "192.168.7.99:8083" does not connect to the application from any other computers on my network.

Unfortunately, I need to be able to connect directly using an IP address as the application is intended to be used via a device that cannot resolve mDNS addresses.

My networking setup is fairly mundane, an Eero system. The host computer is connected to a network switch via ethernet.